# Backing up a Single Table in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

what is the proper way to backup a Single file in Mysql and save it as a .bak Extention?

I tried

```
mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

but i just get a syntax error saying its not a proper statement

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -uUsername -pPassword db_name table_name>C:\table_name.sql
```

-u: your db username

-p your db password

C:\table_name.sql    need be absolute path

Comment: is there a . between the db_name and the table_table?

Comment: also does the path name better? Im doing this in a virtual machine and theres no C drive

Comment: if linux like this : /home/table_name.sql

Comment: I tried this and i got a very weird output https://i.imgur.com/uTwH3Zn.png

Comment: change  :\home\ag715.sql   to  your real path  like   /home/ag715.sql

Comment: i did this "mysql> mysqldump -ucsit115 -pcsit115 csit115 ORDER_DETAIL >:/home/ag715.sql;" and i still get a syntax error

Comment: need change  :\home\ag715.sql   to  your real path  like   /home/ag715.sql

Comment: don't login to mysql

Comment: need change  mysql> mysqldump -ucsit115 -pcsit115 csit115 ORDER_DETAIL >:/home/ag715.sql;

mysql>exit

and then 

mysqldump -ucsit115 -pcsit115 csit115 ORDER_DETAIL >:/home/ag715.sql;

Comment: first   mysql>exit

Comment: and then mysqldump -ucsit115 -pcsit115 csit115 ORDER_DETAIL >:/home/ag715.sql;

Comment: don't login to mysql

Comment: Maybe you can find mysqldump

Comment: > whereis mysql

Comment: mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib64/mysql /usr/local/mysql /usr/share/mysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194284/discussion-between-veretech-and-andrew-van).

Comment: Permission denied  try to login by root user  and then do it again

Comment: okay so i did that properly and it asks for a password but it thinks csit115 is a table

Answer (score 0):

First Make Sure that you run your MYSQL then

```
mysqldump –u[user name] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] [table_name] > dump.sql
```